# Hosting multiple private VPNs on PFSense

Tags: vpn, freebsd, pfsense

We are running PFSense 2.0.1-RELEASE and need to make the following scenario work:
1..n remote offices for company A need to connect to a private VPN (VPN server hosted in our datacenter).  All the devices in all the remote offices need to be on a single subnet and be able to talk to each other.

This is not a problem with the VPN server in PFSense, with a single company.  The problem is  company B.  They have to have a private VPN, and private subnet also.  I don't see a way of creating a second PPTP VPN server in PFSense.

Answer (score 3):

Never use PPTP for site to site VPNs, use IPsec or OpenVPN. It's also pretty much never a good practice to put multiple locations on the same subnet, each should have its own unique subnet with routing between them over the VPN.